# Преобразование переменной javascript в Json

Tags: javascript, json

Есть пример в фотмате JSON который понимает мой плагин, с которым мне надо работать.

```
[{
  "id":1,"text":"Root node","children":[
    {"id":2,"text":"Child node 1"},
    {"id":3,"text":"Child node 2"}
  ]
}]
```

Какая структура у изначальной переменной js должена быть чтобы я мог получить на выходе вышеприведенный JSON используя `JSON.stringify(data);` Где `data` переменная JS.

Comment: такая же и должна

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var data = [{
  "id":1,"text":"Root node","children":[
    {"id":2,"text":"Child node 1"},
    {"id":3,"text":"Child node 2"}
  ]
}]

 document.getElementById('d').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data,null,2);
```

```html
<pre id='d'></pre>
```